# NSProgress::completedUnitCount setter hangs

Tags: ios, uikit, nsprogress

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
            task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
  didSendBodyData:(int64_t)bytesSent
  totalBytesSent:(int64_t)totalBytesSent
  totalBytesExpectedToSend:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToSend
  {
  self.progress.completedUnitCount = totalBytesSent;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this hangs on ios 9.0
  any ideas what to do about this???
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
                              didSendBodyData:(int64_t)bytesSent
                               totalBytesSent:(int64_t)totalBytesSent
                     totalBytesExpectedToSend:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToSend; is invoked on the main thread not that it should matter

(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0xd6e1, 0x00000001984a0c6c libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 8, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', activity = 'send control actions', 1 messages, stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  * frame #0: 0x00000001984a0c6c libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 8
    frame #1: 0x000000019857a97c libsystem_platform.dylib`_os_semaphore_wait + 24
    frame #2: 0x00000001007bd428 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow + 600
    frame #3: 0x00000001835af270 Foundation`-[NSConcreteObservationBuffer _receiveBox:] + 248
    frame #4: 0x00000001836180b0 Foundation`_NSKVO1AdaptorDeliver + 388
    frame #5: 0x0000000183617ea0 Foundation`_NSKVO1AdaptorSlowDeliver + 264
    frame #6: 0x0000000183523b84 Foundation`-[NSKeyValueObservance observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] + 424
    frame #7: 0x00000001834ffdd4 Foundation`NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 304
    frame #8: 0x00000001834ff8fc Foundation`NSKeyValueDidChange + 404
    frame #9: 0x00000001834ea114 Foundation`-[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:] + 120
    frame #10: 0x000000018258fab0 CoreFoundation`__53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 132
    frame #11: 0x000000018258f9a8 CoreFoundation`-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 308
    frame #12: 0x00000001836cc158 Foundation`-[NSProgress _setValueForKeys:settingBlock:] + 600
    frame #13: 0x00000001836cc87c Foundation`-[NSProgress setCompletedUnitCount:] + 124

PS: if I avoid setting UIProgressView::observedProgress to that NSProgress it works fine!?

Answer (score 1):

resolved with busy wait

```
-(void)showUploadingUI
{
myHardAssert([[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread], @"");
self.progressView.hidden = NO;
NSProgress *progress = urlsession.progress;
if( [self.progressView respondsToSelector:@selector(observedProgress)]) {
// this causes hang     self.progressView.observedProgress = progress;
}
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    while(progress.completedUnitCount < progress.totalUnitCount) {
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.progressView.progress = progress.fractionCompleted;
        });
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.033];
    }
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.progressView.progress = 1;
    });
```

....

the side benefit is backwards compatibility for ios < 9

Answer (score 0):

Boy did that help me. My app was freezing when incrementing `Progress.completedUnitCount`. (On the main thread.) I'm assuming this triggers a setter since there is a side-effect — moving the progress bar, the whole reason for doing it.

My Swift 4 solution was to wrap the call like this:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
    self._decompressionProgress.completedUnitCount += 1
}
```

I still don't quite understand why this works... not unlike a lot of things.